# Combinatorics: Number of Six-Card Hands That Can Be Dealt from r Combined Decks

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, binomial-coefficients

I am having trouble solving this combinatorial problem dealing with the number of different card hands possible from multiple decks of identical cards. Here is the exact question:

*Use a combinatorial argument to count the number of different six-card hands that can be dealt from r combined decks, for each positive integer r.*

I assumed that if r > 6 it would not effect the answer because at most a card can be repeated six times. Therefore, I interpreted the question as asking to use a combinatorial argument to count the number of different six-card hands that can be dealt from a sextuple deck.

From that point I found eleven different situations that could occur represented by the following sequences: 123456, 112345, 112234, 112233, 111234, 111223, 111222, 111123, 111122, 111112, 11111. By this notation I mean that the first sequence represents a six-card hand with zero cards repeating, the second contains 1 repeat, the third contains 2 repeats, and the fourth contains 3 repeats.

I then attempted to represent this using binomial coefficients:
$$\binom{52}{6}\binom{6}{0}+\binom{52}{5}\binom{5}{1}+\binom{52}{4}\binom{4}{2}+\binom{52}{3}\binom{3}{3}+\binom{52}{4}\binom{4}{1}+\binom{52}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{52}{2}\binom{2}{2}+\binom{52}{3}\binom{3}{1}+\binom{52}{2}\binom{2}{1}\binom{1}{1}+\binom{52}{2}\binom{2}{1}+\binom{52}{1}\binom{1}{1},$$
but I was mainly confused about the sixth binomfial coefficient $\binom{52}{3}\binom{3}{1}\binom{2}{1}$ representing the sequence 111223 where is one card thrice repeated and another twice repeated. The answer I came up with is 36,288,252 possible hands.

If anyone could help verify my answer or inform me on what I am doing wrong please do.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: A couple of questions.  Why restrict $r$ to simply a sextuple deck?  Do hands include different suits?  In other words, with multiple decks, say 6, you can have 6 aces of spades or 6 aces of hearts or 3 aces of diamonds and 3 of clubs.  Would those just be 6 of a kind (i assume yes, but math has to be precise...)

Comment: I think you need to deal with $r=1$ to $5$ also. But the answers can be obtained by removing the appropriate terms from your calculation with $6$.

Comment: The way I interpreted the question is that a hand of 6 aces of spades and a hand of 6 aces of hearts are considered a different hand. Not sure if that answers your question. Does the third paragraph not explain why I chose to restrict r to a sextuple deck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your numerical answer is correct, but this (the $r=6$ case) can be dealt with much more efficiently using [balls and urns](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Ball-and-urn).  The answer should be a single binomial coefficient.

However, Eleven-Eleven and André are correct that you should not assume $r=6$, especially given the wording of the problem.  For the general case, you can [count the complement](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Complementary_counting) in order to simplify things, though some mild casework may be unavoidable.

It may be instructive to test out your answer for very small values of $6$ and $52$.

Comment: Okay, so using the ball-and-urn technique I can simplify my above expression to $\binom{52+6-1}{6}$. I am confused, however, on the complement counting technique.

Comment: @ConnorBerg For example, take $r=5$.  Of the 36,288,252 hands, how many require six decks?

Comment: Wouldn't only 52 hands require six decks?

Comment: @ConnorBerg Correct, which takes care of $r=5$.  For $r=4$, ask how many require five decks.  $r=3$ may be the most difficult case.

Comment: Here is what I came up with: 52 hands require six decks, 2,652 hands require five decks, 68,952 hands require four decks, 1,151,852 hands require three decks, and 14,641,250 hands require two decks.

Comment: Correction: for r = 2 I got 1,216,826 hands.

Comment: @ConnorBerg I haven't checked all the numbers, but keep in mind that you want to subtract those from 36,288,252 to solve the original problem.

Comment: Is the original problem asking for several different answers? Such as the number of six-card hands for 1 deck, 2 decks, 3 decks, etc?

Comment: @ConnorBerg "For each positive integer $r$".  That's my best interpretation of it.  Grammatically it could also be asking for the number of hands which, for each positive integer $r$, can be dealt with $r$ combined decks... but I doubt it was intended to be that confusing.